# Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $model ]]

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8, I get `Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $model ]]` while inject the model name to repository, I need to pass model name to repository from controller.

**Here is the repository**

```php
    private $model;
    public function __construct($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    // TODO : index
    public function index(){
        return $this->model::get(); 
    } 
    // TODO: Create

    public function create(array $data){
        return $this->model::create($data);
    }

    // TODO: Update
    public function update(array $data , $id){
        $this->model::find($id)->update($data);
    }

    // TODO: Delete
    public function delete($id){
        $this->model::destroy($id); 
    }
}
```

**This is the controller**

```php
{
   
    private $repository;
    private $model;
    public function __construct(Repository $repository , Category $model)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    
    ######################################################################################

    public function index(){
        $categories =  $this->repository->index();
        return $categories;
        // return view('dashboard/category/category' , compact('categories'));
    }
    public function all(){
        
    }

    // Create
    public function store(Request $request){

        $this->model->create($request->all());
    }

    // Update
    public function update($data,$id){

        $this->model->update($id);
    }

    // Delete
    public function Delete($id){

        $this->model->destroy($id);
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I know when i pass only repository in construct it works but what if i need to pass the model too i don, t need to make repository for every model i try to make it more dynamically

Comment: In laravel repository is bad practice - use model scopes for quering.